# No more "about" page, time to change the Informed badge description

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

Currently the [Informed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) description says:

> Read the entire [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page.

And the link https://stackoverflow.com/about redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Since the "about" page was replaced with a "tour" page, guess it's about time to change the summary.

Comment: So, you're saying, it's _about time_ they change it?

Comment: @gunr2171 heh, gotcha! ;)

Comment: I believe people with a reputation of over 20k can change this?  Are you do it yourself @ShadowWizard.  Quoting from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) you can change descriptions of tags?  EDIT - Tags might be considered different to badges

Comment: @PopeyGilbert, only the SE staff/devs can change the descriptions of a badge, or add more/remove badges.

Comment: @gunr2171 Ah, okay, they are different to the descriptions of tags.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert, remember that a tag has a [main info section, or wiki section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) which contains much more information than it's "excerpt", which you may have been confusing. Badges are more "hard-coded" into the system, so letting anyone change them on demand would be a problem.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert once upon a time there were official faq pages that could be edited as a tag wiki, but those were replaced by the help center. Guess that's the source of your confusion. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  More than likely =)  I am easily confused.

Comment: More like time for a new tour badge

Comment: @PlasmaHH "tourist" badge? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I suddenly get discworld associations...

Comment: I already submitted this request as bug report last December on Meta, now MSE. Interesting, it got no traction then. [Informed badge description outdated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211402/238706)

Comment: By the way, I should mention that **only the page name has changed**: the actual content of the tour page is the same as that in the old about page.

Comment: Must be a slow day at Shadow Hogwarts.

Comment: @Palec no badges tag so I missed it when searching, hopefully now either yours or this would draw the required attention. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thought [badges] was too generic, used [informed-badge]. Obviously I made a mistake. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi [no, not really](http://web.archive.org/web/20140327022212/http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That was back when MSO was [meta.se]; now it's a per-site meta. What you've linked to in your post is the tour page for [so].

Comment: Just marking this as completed since it was fixed at least as far back as 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had submitted [the same request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211402/238706) half a year before this one (December 2013), and six hours ago (August 2015) it got [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) from Jon Ericson.

Now, the list of badges refers to “tour” and uses the `/tour` URL. I can confirm that the change is live on Meta Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow and Unix & Linux Stack Exchange – so probably it has been deployed network-wide.